# Fantasy Novel about a man named Q-something who finds a glowing rock in a pool and becomes king

Tags: story-identification

So, I read this series once in middle school. It may be trash, but I vaguely recall enjoying it. I can't find anything about it online. I will post the distinguishing factors I can remember.

1) It had a classic fantasy novel type cover.

2) It was as trilogy, I believe. At least a two-book series.

3) The main character's name started with a Q. I think it was Quenten (some spelling or another) but I'm not certain.

4) The first book is about him being something other than king. I want to say he wasn't royalty at all. He goes on an adventure with some amigos and ends up with an injured arm, but finds a glowing stone in a pool of water while hiding in a cave. The stone makes his arm feel better and eventually is forged into a sword. Yes, very King Arthurian.

5) The novel was older? I want to say it was probably published in the mid 20th century, but that's a guess.

6) There's a "tied upon a wheel" torture type scene in it... I think the school librarians didn't read some of the donations too closely.

I can't recall much about it, such as any words in the title. I hope that this is enough information to jog someone's memory. I don't believe it is a very well known book series, but I thought it was worth a shot.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So, naturally, typing out all the details helped me organize my thoughts and conduct a new search... The book series is "The Dragon King", with the first book being *[In the Hall of the Dragon King](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/140127.In_the_Hall_of_the_Dragon_King)*, published in 1982 by Stephen R. Lawhead. I'll leave deciding if it's actually good or not as an exercise to the reader.

> In the dead of night, Quentin, a young acolyte, is unexpectedly summoned when a mortally wounded knight stumbles into the temple of Ariel. Determined to save the realm of the Dragon King, the dying knight makes a desperate plea for someone to continue his quest. Now Quentin must choose—a life of ease or a dangerous, unknown path.

To find this I searched *Quentin glowing stone pool of water*, which was clearly the defining feature of the books (sarcasm) - the results pointed me to Warlord of Nin which is the 2nd book in the series.

After reading the ploy summaries for books 1 and 2 I saw that it matched the following points that I remembered from reading it years ago.

> 1) It had a classic fantasy novel type cover.

Yes, although the most commonly found cover online now is the 2002 reprint. The copy I read was probably an original 1982 printing (or around then).

> 2) It was as trilogy, I believe. At least a two-book series.

Yes. 3 book series.

> 3) The main character's name started with a Q. I think it was Quenten
>   (some spelling or another) but I'm not certain.

Yes, the main character's name is Quentin.

> 4) The first book is about him being something other than king. I want
>   to say he wasn't royalty at all. He goes on an adventure with some
>   amigos and ends up with an injured arm, but finds a glowing stone in a
>   pool of water while hiding in a cave. The stone makes his arm feel
>   better and eventually is forged into a sword. Yes, very King
>   Arthurian.

The first book is about him being an acolyte and going on a grand quest to save the kingdom. He finds the stone in the water, which does indeed heal his arm, and is indeed forged into a sword.

> 5) The novel was older? I want to say it was probably published in the
>   mid 20th century, but that's a guess.

Original publish date is 1982.

> 6) There's a "tied upon a wheel" torture type scene in it... I think
>   the school librarians didn't read some of the donations too closely.

Yep, this happens. Heavy for a Young Adult novel.

Comment: Self-answers can be accepted 48 hours after asking the question. :) Any chance you can shed some light on how the book series matches up?

Comment: What do you mean? In how well it matches the bullet points I posted?

Comment: Yes. While obviously, this answer satisfies you, providing more details means that the next person who comes along looking for this will have a better chance in finding the book. :)

Comment: How did you find it? What searches did you use?

Comment: Ah. Okay. I'll edit in a search narrative.

Comment: That was an excellent job. :) If you stick around for the next day or so needed, and accept this, I'm inclined to give you a bounty for following up so nicely.

Comment: I'll try to remember. I'm usually on the InfoSec SE daily so some day or another I'll remember to accept my answer.

Comment: I recall the trilogy marginally well and, yes, it's a match with the description.  The only addition I can suggest is that it is very strongly a Christian allegory series, of the sort sold in religious bookstores, and the themes of faith show up throughout.  That is not to say it isn't good Fantasy, as well, but it's less subtle than, say, Narnia.

Comment: I got as far as point 3 and guessed at this series. Thank you for the reminder, I just might read it again some day. Still have the books ...

Comment: Bounty rewarded. :)